# Rendering a chart with colored tiles in React

Tags: reactjs, background-image

I would like to how I can render this kind of chart in React. Especially I am wondering how I can create such a tiled background with different colors and have one or more points with coordinates where x and y can be any number from 1-4.

[image]

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Your question needs improvement.

Comment: That looks like a single background image with a grid of child elements having white borders to me. Also, it's not really a chart. You'd reference the elements by index or other state property.

Answer (score 0):

The Grid can be done like this.

```
function Rect() {
  return <div style={{
    height: "96px",
    width: "96px",
    backgroundColor: "transparent",
    border: "solid 2px white"
  }}></div>;
}

function App() {
  return (
    <div style={{
      background: "linear-gradient(45deg, #53A658, yellow 50%, #ED564D)",
      height: "400px",
      width: "400px",
      display: "flex",
      flexWrap: "wrap"
    }}>
      {new Array(16).fill(1).map(n => <Rect/>)}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

[image]