# Map to a div grid

Tags: reactjs, mapping, closures

I am attempting to adapt the following so that 4x4 grid has numbers 1 through n displayed. Each div cell needs an onclick handler.

I tried tinkering the last response from [Rendering a chart with colored tiles in React](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72060163/rendering-a-chart-with-colored-tiles-in-react)

```
function App() {
     
  
  return (
    <div style={{
      background: "",
      height: "400px",
      width: "400px",
      display: "flex",
      flexWrap: "wrap"
    }}>
      {new Array(16).fill(1).map(n =>{  return <div style={{
    height: "96px",
    width: "96px",
    backgroundColor: "transparent",
    border: "solid 2px white"
  }}>{n}</div>})}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

How to get the numbers 1...16 on each cell? I tried {n} in the div above - didn't help. How to add on click event handler on each div and get the number inside it?

Comment: How to get the numbers 1...16 on each cell? I tried {n} in the div above - didn't help. How to add on click event handler on each div and get the number inside it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the question. The solution can be obtained with just a few tweaks.

If you change things as below you will arrive at the solution. Have added comments in the code to highlight the changed portion.

```
function App() {
     
  
  return (
    <div style={{
      background: "",
      height: "400px",
      width: "400px",
      display: "flex",
      flexWrap: "wrap"
    }}>
      // Additional map to convert Array fill to the index values instead
      {new Array(16).fill().map((_, i) => i+1).map(n =>{  return <div style={{
    height: "96px",
    width: "96px",
    backgroundColor: "transparent",
    cursor: "pointer", // Showing mouse correctly for click action
    border: "solid 2px white",
  }} onClick={() => console.log(n)}>{n}</div>})} // Added a simple onClick function
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

This is just a rough code, I am sure that this code would be part of a larger react app and components should be used to better organize things.